# videojs hls doesn't work on android

Tags: javascript, android, html, video.js

Hi videojs hls plugin doesn't work on android but it works on chrome,firefox,safari,ios not sure what is the problem on android

```
<video id=example-video width=960 height=540 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
  <source
     src="https://example.com/index.m3u8"
     type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
<script src="video.js"></script>
<script src="videojs.hls.min.js"></script>
<script>
var player = videojs('example-video');
player.play();
</script>
```

i tried to use 5.10 - 5.11.9 but still no success

also example of videojs doesn't work too

https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/

```
video.js:21202VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.
```

[https://i.imgur.com/r70Cotj.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofvoj.jpg)

Comment: you are using android chorme or firefox? i think it should be fine if you are using the latest version

Comment: Try video.js version 5.13.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found the reason i was blocking other referers than my domains by nginx

```
valid_referers mysite.tv;

if ($invalid_referer) {
return 403; 
}
```

i tried to sniff android by fiddler and see android just doesnt send

```
Referer
```

header . when i disabled it , started to work. thanks